# OOP the other method if is not working why?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

I do not know why the if statement is not working in the program.
When order is greater than bulkorder, it still returns 0.
Do you think there is a problem with the code I have written which is shown below?

```
public class ShoeStoreOrder{ //ShoeStoreOrder .java
    // private method
     private String typeofshoe ;
     private String season ;
     private double cost ;
     private int bulkOrderQuantity;
     private int discount;
     private int order;
     //constructor
     public ShoeStoreOrder(String t,String s,double c,int b,int d,int o){
     typeofshoe = t;
     season = s;
     cost = c;
     bulkOrderQuantity = b;
     discount = d;
     order = o;
     }
     //get Method
     public String gettypeofshoe(){
     return typeofshoe;
     }
     public String getseason(){
     return season;
     }
     public double getcost(){
     return cost;
     }
     public int getbulkOrderQuantity(){
     return bulkOrderQuantity;
     }
     public int getdiscount(){
     return discount;
     }
     public int getorder(){
     return order;
     }

     //set method 
     public void settypeofshoe(String t){
     typeofshoe=t;
     }
     public void setseason(String s){
     season=s;
     }
     public void setcost(double c){
     cost=c;
     }
     public void setbulkOrderQuantity(int b){
     bulkOrderQuantity=b;
     }
     public void setorder(int o){
     order=o;
     }
     //other method


     //overload method 
    public double gettotaldiscount(){
      if(order()>bulkOrderQuantity()){
      return order*cost*(discount/100);
      }
      else{
      return 0;
      }
      }
     public double gettotalamount(){
     return order*cost-gettotaldiscount();
     }
    }
```

Comment: public double gettotaldiscount(){
  if(order>bulkOrderQuantity){
  return order*cost*(discount/100);
  }
  else{
  return 0;
  }

Comment: Try this: if(getorder()>getbulkOrderQuantity()){
  return order*cost*(discount/100);
  }
  else{
  return 0;
  }

Comment: The problem has been explained, so I'll just point some improvements. You should review the naming conventions like typeofshoe should be typeOfShoe, it is a good idea to use this. before using the attributes like this.typeOfShoe = t and tge camelback case should be used with methods as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have skipped case when order value equals bulkOrderQuantity:

```
public double gettotaldiscount() {
    if (order >= bulkOrderQuantity) {
        return order * cost * discount / 100;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

//Check input and results:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShoeStoreOrder sso;
    System.out.println("No discount");
    sso = new ShoeStoreOrder("vertical", "winter", 20, 5, 10, 1);
    System.out.println(sso.gettotalamount());

    System.out.println("After discount");
    sso = new ShoeStoreOrder("vertical", "winter", 20, 5, 10, 5);
    System.out.println(sso.gettotalamount());

    sso = new ShoeStoreOrder("vertical", "winter", 20, 5, 10, 50);
    System.out.println(sso.gettotalamount());
}
```

Output:

- No discount
- 20.0
- After discount
- 90.0
- 900.0

Answer (score 2):

`order` and `bulkOrderQuantity` are instance variable and not a method. `()` are used when calling a method and not when referencing a variable:

```
  if(order()>bulkOrderQuantity()){
```

change it to

```
  if(order>bulkOrderQuantity){
```

Comment: when order bigger than bulk order, it still returns 0